# Trazer valores do DataFrame2 para o DataFrame1 [Pandas + Python]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Salve pessoal!

Estou em fase de aprendizado com o Python, e tenho a necessidade de agrupar a descrição idêntica do mesmo ID que estão na Tabela 2, e retornar em colunas diferente na Tabela 1.

Tabela - 1

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Tabela - 2

| ID | Descrição | Valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DescA | 1 |
| 1 | DescB | 2 |
| 2 | DescB | 3 |
| 2 | DescB | 1 |
| 3 | DescA | 2 |
| 3 | DescA | 3 |

Tabela_1 após somar valores da Tabela_2

| ID | DescA | DescB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 |

Alguma sugestão de como posso fazer isto?

Obrigado desde já pela contribuição.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando Pandas, você pode simplesmente pivotar a tabela 2 com pd.pivot_table() e utilizando soma para agregação. Ele irá unir as linhas com  mesmo índice agregando por soma. Depois disso, fazer um merge entre as duas (como o left join do sql):

```
import pandas as pd

#Criando a tabela2: df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,2,2,3,3],
                    "Descricao": ["DescA","DescB","DescB","DescB","DescA","DescA"],
                    "Valor": [1,2,3,1,2,3]})

#Pivotando
df2_pivot = pd.pivot_table(data=df2, aggfunc="sum", index="id",columns="Descricao", values="Valor")

#Merge das tabelas
df_final = df1.merge(df2_pivot, on=["id"], how="left")

#Para substituir os NaN por 0, se houver
df_final = df_final.fillna("0")
```

Para mais detalhes a [documentação está aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

Comment: Olá Cezar, obrigado pelo breve retorno. Mas na verdade, preciso retornar os dados da tabela_2 na tabela_1, haja visto que posso ter mais id's. Acredito que eu possa não ter sido claro neste ponto. Grato

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Editei a resposta e inclui um merge com a tabela 1 para trazer os dados da tabela 2 para a 1.

Comment: Perfeito Cezar, foi certeiro na resposta. Fico grato pelo apoio.